# Is there a way to pass a parameter to a command through a keybinding done in code?

Tags: wpf, wpf-controls, c#-4.0, command, key-bindings

I am making a custom control I need to add some default keybindings, microsoft has already done with copy and paste in a textbox. However one of the keybindings needs to pass a parameter to the command which it is bound to. It is simple to do this in xaml, is there any way to do this in code?

```
this.InputBindings.Add(new KeyBinding(ChangeToRepositoryCommand, new KeyGesture(Key.F1)));
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I found the answer:

```
InputBindings.Add(new KeyBinding(ChangeToRepositoryCommand, new KeyGesture(Key.F1)) { CommandParameter = 0 });
```

I apologize if my question was unclear.

Comment: Your solution is much more readable this way: `InputBindings.Add(new KeyBinding(ChangeToRepositoryCommand, new KeyGesture(Key.F1)) { CommandParameter = 0 });`

Answer (score 1):

The copy and paste commands are handled by the text box so parameters are not strictly passed, but i know what you are getting at.

I do this using a hack - and an attached property, like so

```
   public class AttachableParameter : DependencyObject {

      public static Object GetParameter(DependencyObject obj) {
         return (Object)obj.GetValue(ParameterProperty);
      }

      public static void SetParameter(DependencyObject obj, Object value) {
         obj.SetValue(ParameterProperty, value);
      }

      // Using a DependencyProperty as the backing store for Parameter.  This enables animation, styling, binding, etc...
      public static readonly DependencyProperty ParameterProperty =
          DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached("Parameter", typeof(Object), typeof(AttachableParameter), new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(null, FrameworkPropertyMetadataOptions.Inherits));
}
```

then in the xaml

```
<ListBox local:AttachableParameter.Parameter="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}, Path=SelectedItems}" />
```

which makes the parameter the selected items

then when the command fires on the window i use this to see if the command parameter is there (i call this from the can execute and the Executed)

```
  private Object GetCommandParameter() {
     Object parameter = null;
     UIElement element = FocusManager.GetFocusedElement(this) as UIElement;
     if (element != null) {
        parameter = AttachableParameter.GetParameter(element as DependencyObject);
     }
     return parameter;
  }
```

It is a hack, but i have not found another way to get the command parameter for a binding that is fired from a key binding. (I would love to know a better way)

Comment: It's so easy to do what I need in xaml with:
<KeyBinding Command="{Binding ChangeRepositoryCommand}" Gesture="Ctrl+1" CommandParameter="0"/>

I wonder why they don't let you do it in code.